# accessing property of other component?

Tags: angular

I'm creating an inventory management project on my own from scratch. Now I'm hitting the wall.

I have completed the feature that lets users add items to the inventory but what I'm struggling with is that I want to access the variable that holds the stock item(in stock component) so that I can use it in sales component where users can choose what to sell from the list of inventory available and after that the targeted item should be deducted from the list.

I tried to use service but not sure if it's the right way to do.
Here's my code from StockComponent

```ts
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { StockService } from '../stock.service';
import { Stock } from './stock.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-stock',
  templateUrl: './stock.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stock.component.css'],
  providers: [StockService]
})
export class StockComponent implements OnInit {
  Stocks: Stock[];

  constructor(private stockService: StockService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.Stocks = this.stockService.getStock();
    console.log(this.Stocks);
    console.log(this.stockService.Stocks);
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const value = form.value;
    const dateAdd = new Date();
    const newStock = new Stock(value.id, value.name, value.amount, value.unit, value.type, dateAdd, value.cost, value.remark);
    this.Stocks.push(newStock);
    console.log(this.Stocks);
    console.log(this.stockService.Stocks);
  }
```

And here's my code from StockService

```ts
import { Stock } from "./stock/stock.model";

export class StockService {
  Stocks: Stock[] = [
    new Stock(1, 'OG Kush', 10, 'Grams', 'Kanja', new Date, 1000, 'test'), new Stock(2, 'Thai Stick', 50, 'Grams', 'Kanja', new Date, 2000, 'test remark')
  ];

  getStock() {
    return this.Stocks.slice();
  }
}
```

The problem of my code is it won't update the property in the Stock.Service which will then later be passed and used in sales.component.

Comment: Have you tried updating the `Stocks` property of the `StockService` inside the `onSubmit` handler? After you push the new stock inside `this.Stocks`, try going for `this.stockService.Stocks = [....this.Stocks];`

Comment: @Thanapol, whe you use `provider` in a component you're creating a new instance of the service, just add `provide{in root}` in your service, see the [docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#create-the-heroservice). Note: In general if ther'e not realtionship of father/son between the component you should use a service. If the components are at time in the app (and is in the some <router-outlet> you can use a template reference variable, else use Input/Output (again see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs))